# Young adult time travel novel where the hero is recruited by a good scientist and tempted by his evil doppelganger

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, novel, young-adult

A teenager meets a scientist and his daughter, and discovers that they can travel in time.  In the book, time travel into the past can create overlapping branches, potentially leading towards chaos.
An evil (or just self-serving and corrupt) version of the scientist and his daughter show up, and tempt the young man into working for them.

Part of the plot involves a hideout far in the past, in the arctic, where there's no chance of affecting causality.
The young man is abandoned there for awhile, then rescued...
There's a nightmarish scene involving elevators stopping on multiple floors at the same time, and a sequence where the young man sees the scientist doing an elaborate exercise routine with leaps and hurdles, that turns out to be practice for a heist of some kind.

Answer (score 5):

The book is [Strange Attractors](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0140345825) by William Sleator.

Comment: Of course it is...
I'm more than a little embarrassed that I didn't make that connection on my own, given that I've got another half dozen of his books on my shelf! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.  Don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: Note: from information available to moderators, user7495 is very likely a duplicate account belonging to the OP. Therefore the [confirmation comment](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/19151/young-adult-time-travel-novel-where-the-hero-is-recruited-by-a-good-scientist-an#comment36237_19216) above constitutes acceptance of this answer.