# Boy travels through time using a calculator

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel

I read a book from the late 80's when I was 13 or 14 about a boy who travels through time using a calculator. I don't remember too much detail...but I do know that he was on the run from a bad guy who was chasing him and trying to take the calculator. The bad guy might have had a time traveling calculator as well because I remember him chasing him through time.

He got the calculator from a scientist and he was friends with the scientist's daughter. I know that both kids were teenagers, but I don't remember too much more than that.

I never got to finish the book...and for some odd reason, I really want to.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/19151/young-adult-time-travel-novel-where-the-hero-is-recruited-by-a-good-scientist-an (which does not have an accepted answer but seems to contain a confirmation comment, presumably by the OP)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This might be [Strange Attractors](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0140345825) by William Sleator.

I haven't read it but a plot summary on Amazon says it's about, not time travel exactly, but moving between multiple timelines.  Actually it sort of reminds me of *Sliders*.  It was published in 1990, so it pre-dates *Sliders*.

[image: Cover]

Comment: It is Strange Attractors; the calculator does enable time travel, but traveling to the past accidentally generates multiple timelines.  Every time.  Fun book.

Comment: That's definitely the book! Thank you very much!